# Calculating multiple parameters for a logarithmic function

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, logarithms, systems-of-equations

I have the following function -

$$y=\ln(Ax^D+B+Cx^E)$$

These are the coordinates:
$$(1, 1)$$$$(2, 0.84)$$$$(4, 1.5)$$$$(31, 4.1)$$$$(44, 5)$$

How can you solve this equation and what is the correct method for finding the $A,B,C,D$ and $E$ parameters?

**EDIT**

It seems that the last coordinate is causing a problem.
Anyway what's the correct way to find the equation without the last coordinate and as close as possible?

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ragn6n1qqr

Comment: I've also tried to play with desmos but I couldn't get the exact function, so the question is what's the correct way to solve this

Comment: The fact that Desmos is giving us $R^2=.9955\neq 1$ makes me suspect there isn't a set of parameters that $A,B,C,D,E$ which satisfy those points.

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Comment: @Drxxd you don't fit logs: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ragn6n1qqr

Comment: It's a problem that I have in my project, I have a set of discrete input parameters for x and I need to find a function that resembles the equation in the question as close as possible.. Maybe I'll try to ask a more specific question about finding this function

Comment: @Mason Probably the last coordinate is causing the problem, anyway how can we find it without the last coordinate or as close as possible? Is there a specific method? or the best way is to just use desmos and try to get the parameters randomly?

Comment: True. With $4$ points and not $5$ we get $R=1$. One thing to think about is why exactly that is... It looks like you have given us 5 variables to mess with and 5 conditions to meet but I suspect that one variable isn't very helpful. If we factor out $A$ and write it $\ln(A)+ Expression$ we see that one of these variables really only lets us slide the graph up and down.

Comment: @Mason fitting the points in semi-log scale gives $R^2 = 1$ even with the fifth point https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vm1eh3qb28 sorry for the link before, I just realised that I gave your link instead of mine

Comment: We need $5$ different equations as there are $5$ unknowns. Are you sure that the last point is $(44,5)$?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to say that the *last* coordinate is causing a problem. Maybe the five coordinate pairs are incompatible with the given model, but you cannot attribute this to a particular value. And if you discard data, the system becomes undeterminate.

Comment: @YvesDaoust You're right.. The model is probably wrong, I'll try to ask a more specific question about the model..

Comment: What?!?! Probably wrong? $R^2=.9955$ seems like your model is wrong in the way that makes engineers/scientists drool...

Comment: We were too harsh with Davide. I am liking his approach more and more...

Comment: @Mason: this is a system of five equation in five unknowns, so that *any* model can achieve a perfect fit $R=1$, unless some points are out of the domain.

Comment: @Mason His approach and mine are the same...

Comment: @Mason: it is no rocket science that the $\log$ can/should be discarded, but this doesn't really make the nonlinear problem easier.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. And I am liking the approach more and more.

Comment: @Mason lol I'm not a mathematician (yet), anyway I've posted a more specific question - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2852333/how-to-find-a-non-linear-model-that-fits-a-set-of-coordinates

Comment: @Mason ahah don't worry! It wasn't my brightest moment, got wrong too many things! My line of reasoning wanted to be the same as the answer of@YvesDaoust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Too long for a comment, but may be of some use:**

I have omitted the last set of coordinates as the OP has requested.

Substitute $(1,1)$: $$A+B+C=e\tag{1}$$

Substitute $(2,0.84)$: $$A\cdot2^D+C\cdot2^E+B=e^{0.84}\tag{2}$$

Substitute $(4,1.5)$: $$A\cdot2^{2D}+C\cdot2^{2E}+B=e^4\tag{3}$$

Substitute $(31,4.1)$: $$A\cdot31^D+C\cdot31^E+B=e^{4.1}\tag{4}$$

Do $(3)-(2)$: $$A\cdot2^D(2^D-1)+C\cdot2^E(2^E-1)=e^4-e^{0.84}\tag{5}$$

Do $(2)-(1)$: $$A\cdot(2^D-1)+C\cdot(2^E-1)=e^{0.84}-e\tag{6}$$

Simultaneous equation so solve for $A$ and $C$ in terms of $D$ and $E$.

Multiply $(7)$ by $2^E$: $$A\cdot2^E(2^D-1)+C\cdot2^E(2^E-1)=2^E(e^4-e^{0.84})\tag{7}$$

Do $(8)-(6)$: $$A(2^E-2^D)(2^D-1)=(2^E-1)(e^4-e^{0.84})$$ so $$A=\frac{(2^E-1)(e^4-e^{0.84})}{(2^E-2^D)(2^D-1)}\tag{8}$$

Substitute $(9)$ into $(7)$: $$C=\frac{(2^E-2^D)(e^{0.84}-e)-(2^E-1)(e^4-e^{0.84})}{(2^E-2^D)(2^D-1)}\tag{9}$$

Substitute $(9)$ and $(10)$ into $(1)$: $$B=e-\frac{e^{0.84}-e}{2^D-1}\tag{10}$$

Now $A$ and $C$ are in terms of $D$ and $E$, but $B$ is only in terms of $D$.

Comment: If we had another equation then the expressions for $A,B,C$ could be substituted into the remaining two equations and could be solved simultaneously.

Comment: That's great for this moment.. Thanks!

Comment: You have a mistake in (3) where it's supposed to be: A*2**(D+1)  + C*2**(E+1) + B = e**4

Comment: it's supposed to be also e\**1.5 (not e\**4)

Comment: No, $4^D=(2^2)^D=2^{2D}\neq2^{D+1}$

Comment: the concept is still the same whether it is 1.5 or 4

Comment: Dude, 4\**D does not equal to 2\**(2D).  4\**D=2\**(D+1)

Comment: Are you sure? Try $D=5$...

Comment: My bad lol.. I tried it on desmos and it didn't give me the correct graph when I plugged in the A,B and C parameters, so I tried to figure out what's wrong with the solution

Answer (score 0):

The model

$$Ax^D+B+Cx^E=e^y$$ is partly linear and partly nonlinear and has no closed-form solution. You can make it slightly more tractable numerically by plugging the coordinates of the five points to obtain five equations, and eliminate the coefficients $A,B,C$ by forming linear combinations (for instance, you can solve the three first equations by Cramer and plug in the remaining two).

In the end, you will obtain as simplified system of two equations in the two unknowns $D$ and $E$ (though these equations involve ten exponentials). This can be solved by Newton in a less costly way than the original system, and as there are only two independent variables left, graphical observation is possible.